# Angular ng-style not working with kendo grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I am not able to put a blue color in the grid when the surname is empty.

I am using Kendo grid, and I am not very familiar with how to write angular code inside of a kendo row template.

Here is my code: http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcosjroig/eQUye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass stringfied object to `ng-style` which is available there in `Style` column

```
<td ng-style= "#: Style && JSON.stringify(Style) #">
   #: Surname #
</td>
```

[**Dojo**](http://dojo.telerik.com/IPuGo)

Comment: Thanks, in order to get it working, now I need to make work the kendo grid refresh. So the style has to be applied after the For loop finishes. this line is not working too: //angular.element("#testKendoGrid").data("kendo-grid").dataSource.data($scope.dataJson);
      //angular.element("#testKendoGrid").data("kendo-grid").dataSource.page(0); Can you please help also with this? Thanks

Comment: @MarcosF8 why, it should work without refresh. look at the attached dojo fiddle.. I don't see where the issue is ??

Comment: For the third row of the json: FirstName: "Eddy" has hardcoded the style. Remove it and the code does not work anymore.

Comment: need a kind of $q.All or something to wait until the for finishes and then assign the model to the grid.

Comment: @MarcosF8 it seems to be working fine for me.. could you please check this out http://dojo.telerik.com/IPuGo/3

Comment: yes, it is working fine too me too. Taking out the debugger it still works, thanks a lot, great help, I hate kendo but I have to use it :)